# Unable to log in to Azure web app via VS2015 web performance test

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, load-testing

How do I correctly handle the login/authentication scenario for an Azure web app in my VS2015 web performance test?

I created an XML file as a data source for the WAAD username and password. I bind the username and password to the Form Post Parameters: login and passwd respectively at request: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/login
But when I run the test, the Web Browser tab shows this error:

> We can't sign you in
>
> Your browser is currently set to block JavaScript. You need to allow
>   JavaScript to use this service.
>
> To learn how to allow JavaScript or to find out whether your browser
>   supports JavaScript, check the online help in your web browser.

I also get a number of errors like this:

> The value of the ExpectedResponseUrl property
>   Validation    xxxx.azurewebsites.net/xxxx/docs/xxxx.aspx does
>   not equal the actual response URL
>   login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/wsfed.  QueryString
>   parameters were ignored.

Any idea how I can successfully log in to the Azure web app via the web performance test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods of login and authentication that can be used. Just binding values to form post parameters may not be sufficient or correct. You will find the login form has hidden session identities that must be passed as well as the login data. I find that recording a test two times using as nearly as possible the same inputs and doing the same activities helps. These two tests can then be compared to find the dynamic data that needs to be handled.

In a comment the questioner added *"I noticed these parameters, n1-43 are different but I have no idea what they represent. How do I handle them?"*. I can have no idea what they represent as I do not know the website you are testing. You could ask the website developers. Or, better, treat them as dynamic data. Find where the values come from, save them into context variables and use them as needed. This is basic web test development. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2007/04/10/how-to-debug-a-web-test/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edglas/2010/03/23/web-test-authoring-and-debugging-techniques-for-visual-studio-2010/) are two good articles on what to do.

The message about JavaScript not being supported can be ignored. Visual Studio web tests do not support JavaScript or any other "active" parts of a web page, they only support the html part. Your job as a tester is to simulate what the JavaScript does for the specific user journeys you are testing. That simulation is generally just filling in the correct values (via context parameters) in the recorded requests.

Unexpected response urls can be due to earlier failures, such as teh login not working. I suggest not worrying about them until all of the other test problems are solved. Then, if you need help ask another new question.

Comment: As suggested, I recorded these steps twice: 1. Enter my web app URL; 2. Enter the same username and password at Microsoft login page; 3. Web app default page is shown. I noticed these parameters, n1-43 are different but I have no idea what they represent. How do I handle them?  I have searched Microsoft forums on the same topic, but I cannot find anything on these parameters.